# JSON response from an URL / Classic ASP

Tags: javascript, json, asp-classic

Hello and thanks in advanced,this is my first time with Json and I'm quite lost. Basically what I need to achieve is making a call to an url(www.whatever.com?radius=300&type=sale for example),this call's response is formated as a json

```
["pisos, áticos, estudios, dúplex, casas o chalets, de todos los precios, de todos los tamaños, con 0 dormitorios o más",
{
  "total" : 1,
  "elementList":[
            { "abrAddress" : "cervantes, 36",
              "address" : "cervantes, 36",
              "agency" : true,
              "agentLogo" : "www.idealista.com/publicidad/P00015394.gif",
              "bathrooms" : 0,
              "condition" : "obra nueva",
            }

            ],

    "actualPage" : 1,
    "totalPages" : 1,
    "itemsPerPage" : 20
},
{ "latitude" : 40.415914000000001,
"longitude" : -3.696148}
]
```

Then I have to procress this data.

I'm doing all of this from within a classic asp file,and basically I have no idea how to start making the call or whatsoever,I've google around and I cant seem to find a single example where they get the json data from a call to an url etc.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please clarify - are you sending or receiving the JSON? Does this site have any API documentation describing how to properly call for the data?

Comment: I'm recieving the data the site is: http://www.idealista.com/labs/api.htm?action=help#json , the call should be an url with parameteres "http://www.idealista.com/labs/propertyMap.htm?action=json&operation=V&radio=40.41766848762555,-3.69614839553833&center=40.415914,-3.696148", You need an api key so it wont work if u click from this site.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
Set objRequest = Server.createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0") 
objRequest.open "POST", url here, False 

objRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" 
objRequest.setRequestHeader "CharSet", "utf-8" 
objRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", url here

objRequest.send JSONstr

set objJSONDoc = nothing 
set objResult = nothing
```